# how to get my $genderRadio is defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take a survey you can say: I'm asking a question if they work out a lot or not, then I have different questions for them if they do or don't work out a lot. And then I am asking them if they are female or male. My goal is to give them feedback based on all three things, sex, if they work out or not, and how they answer questions. I am looking for someone to explain to me what i am doing wrong here and if they could get my fiddle working for me, i would be most thankful!

```
 $output.addClass('error');
 var dropdownValue = $('.myOptions').val(),
 $genderRadio = $('input[name=gender]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xM2f/19/

Comment: Please add relevant html too.

Comment: Not sure why, but this is working: http://jsfiddle.net/7xM2f/20/

Comment: $ symbol is used in PHP and jQuery, but not for js variables

Comment: @xmashallax: it is perfectly legal to start javascript variables with a $ symbol, and it can be quite useful to distinguish between jQuery objects and regular javascript variables.

Comment: I don't use jQuery, so your point might be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some undefined variables. You were attempting to use them **before** you defined them. The correction is to define them prior to their use:

```
...
var $output = $('#output'); // define $output before
var $output1 = $('#output1'); // define $output1 before

$('#butt').click(function () {
    // change $genderRadio to the jquery selector directly here
    var tt = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
...
```

That's all your fiddled needed to work. [Check the updated version here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/7xM2f/24/)

Next time, you can solve those problems by **watching the console**. In Chrome and IE you can see it in the ***Developer Tools*** - `console` tab, that opens with the <kbd>F12</kbd> key. In Firefox, the ***Web Console*** is opened using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, but the most widely used tool is the [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) (<kbd>F12</kbd> opens its console as well).